# Match array values to object property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've been having problems trying to match an array values taken from a query string to an object properties and return a child object when there's a match.

My array:

```
["model1-all", "model2-all", "model3-all"]
```

the array can be empty or return one, two or all values.

My object:

```
[
  {
    "model1-all": [
      {
        "text": "Model1",
        "id": "model1-all",
        "image": "http://example.com/images/model1/front.png",
        "models": [
          {
            "id": "model1-all",
            "text": "All",
            "positiveFeatureCopy": null,
            "negativeFeatureCopy": null,
            "weight": 1000
          },
          {
            "id": "model1-coupe",
            "text": "Coupe",
            "positiveFeatureCopy": null,
            "negativeFeatureCopy": null,
            "weight": 1000
          },
          {
            "id": "model1-convertible",
            "text": "Convertible",
            "positiveFeatureCopy": null,
            "negativeFeatureCopy": null,
            "weight": 1000
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "model2-all": [
      {
        "text": "Model2",
        "id": "model2-all",
        "image": "http://example.com/images/model2/front.png",
        "models": [
          {
            "id": "model2-all",
            "text": "All",
            "positiveFeatureCopy": null,
            "negativeFeatureCopy": null,
            "weight": 1000
          },
          {
            "id": "model2-hatchback",
            "text": "Hatchback",
            "positiveFeatureCopy": null,
            "negativeFeatureCopy": null,
            "weight": 1000
          },
          {
            "id": "model2-convertible",
            "text": "Convertible",
            "positiveFeatureCopy": null,
            "negativeFeatureCopy": null,
            "weight": 1000
          },
          {
            "id": "model2-estate",
            "text": "Estate",
            "positiveFeatureCopy": null,
            "negativeFeatureCopy": null,
            "weight": 1000
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "model3-all": [
      {
        "text": "Model3",
        "id": "model3-all",
        "image": "http://example.com/images/model3/front.png",
        "models": [
          {
            "id": "model3-all",
            "text": "All",
            "positiveFeatureCopy": null,
            "negativeFeatureCopy": null,
            "weight": 1000
          },
          {
            "id": "model3-saloon",
            "text": "Saloon",
            "positiveFeatureCopy": null,
            "negativeFeatureCopy": null,
            "weight": 1000
          },
          {
            "id": "model3-estate",
            "text": "Estate",
            "positiveFeatureCopy": null,
            "negativeFeatureCopy": null,
            "weight": 1000
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What I need to achieve is that when there's a value in the array that matches one of the objects, e.g. `[{"model1-all" : [...`, I want to return its child object:

```
    "models": [
                 {"id":"model1-all", "...":"....", "...", "...":"..."},
                 {"id":"model1-coupe", "...":"....", "...", "...":"..."},
                 {"id":"model1-convertible", "...":"....", "...", "...":"..."}
              ]
```

I can use either jQuery or Underscore.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for jQuery

```
var models = [];
var matches = ["model1-all", "model2-all", "model3-all"];

for (var key in data[0]) {
    //No indexOf for IE8 compatibility
    if (matches.indexOf(key) > -1) {
        models.push({
            id: key,
            child: data[0][key]
        });
    }

    //Not using indexOf
    for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        if (matches[i] == key) {
            models.push({
                id: key,
                child: data[0][key]
            });
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Results in

```
models = [
    {
        id: "model1-all",
        child: <object from model1-all>
    },
    ..
]
```

Comment: Hey tymeJV, thanks! Unfortunately though, can't use indexOf(), because it has to be compatible with IE8 :/